# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground(); Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Sometimes i get this crash error in my app When I click the button several times, it will be crash, the button is send the SOAP request to the server, and the full logcat in the following：

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16290): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at enter code herejava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at com.bgi.genebook.task.QueryCalAllDataTask.doInBackground(QueryCalAllDataTask.java:24)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at com.bgi.genebook.task.QueryCalAllDataTask.doInBackground(QueryCalAllDataTask.java:1)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-06 15:17:16.003: E/AndroidRuntime(16290):    ... 4 more
```

the button on click will be running the code:

```
Map<String, Object> mapSyc = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapSyc.clear();
QueryCalAllDataTask<VipOxygen> task = new QueryCalAllDataTask<VipOxygen>(
                this);
mapSyc.put("date", date);
mapSyc.put("wsdl", VipBloodOxygenWebService.wsdl);
task.execute(mapSyc);
```

and the QueryCalAllDataTask.java is:

```
public class QueryCalAllDataTask<T> extends
        AsyncTask<Map<String, Object>, Integer, List<Map<String, String>>> {
    GBListener<T> listener;

    public QueryCalAllDataTask(GBListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized List<Map<String, String>> doInBackground(Map<String, Object>... params) {
        List<Map<String, String>> contentListDay = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Log.e("OPERATE", params[0].get("wsdl").toString()); // line 24
        try{
        contentListDay = (List<Map<String, String>>)BaseWebService.getDataAllDaysCountOfMouth(params[0]
                .get("wsdl").toString(), params[0].get("date").toString());
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return contentListDay;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> list) {
        System.out.println("QueryTask.onPostExecute()" + list);
        listener.getAllCalData(list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        System.out.println(values);
    }

}
```

who can help me?and why? this crash appear once in a while When I click the button several times!

Comment: *who can help me?and why?* WHY anybody?

Comment: why would anybody help me?? This life has no sense!! WHY??

Comment: The error occurs in line 24 in the file `QueryCalAllDataTask.java`. Since I don't know what's in that line, I can't help you more.

Comment: -1 for empty catch block.

Comment: Not just an empty catch block. `.getDataAllDaysCountOfMo` **`u`** `th`... Silently ignoring all but the first parameter... Initializing `contentListDay`, only to overwrite it in the `try`... The fact that `contentListDay` exists at all (just `return` the function call!)...

Answer (score 1):

The error is most surely here:

```
contentListDay = (List<Map<String, String>>)BaseWebService.
getDataAllDaysCountOfMouth(params[0].get("wsdl").toString(),  
params[0].get("date").toString());
```

I don't know which one of `get("wsdl")` and `get("date")` is returning null, anyway, you should never call a method on the object without knowing if the object exists or it's `null`.

Before calling `toString(),` you should check that. Something like:

```
 something = params[0].get("wsdl");

 if (something==null)
     System.out.println("Can't get parameter wsdl");
 else
     something.toString();
```

Do the same with the parameter `date` and you'd be able to know what's returning null there, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible operation in your code, which could cause `NPE` exception is this one `params[0].get("wsdl").toString()`.

It means, that your first param (with index `0`) hasn't `wsdl` key in it.

Comment: As I expected the problem is in exactly that line. Read my answer, the problem is with empty (null) value with key `wsdl` - it is empty.

Comment: I know the problem is with empty ,but why it is null ? I have set the key and value into the map when the button is clicked!

Comment: @wonday may be `VipBloodOxygenWebService.wsdl` is null?

Comment: I don't konw, but when click the button slowly ,it will be no problem, only when i click the button quickly, it wiil be crash!